# What does the value Default of Duplex in System.Drawing.Printing mean?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, printing, .net-4.8

I have a Kyocera printer and I can print documents from my WinForms app. I need to change the duplex mode from within the app.

In the printer preferences I can set the duplex mode to: Off, Long-edge, Short-edge. This would correspond to the following Duplex enum values: Simplex, Vertical, Horizontal.

So, if for example, I set the setting to Long-edge in the printer preferences, and I check the Duplex value of the `PrinterSettings` instance, the value is Vertical. The same applies for the other 2 options.

So what does the Default value do?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.duplex?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0), `Default (-1)` is whatever the default setting is *on the printer*. This implies it's printer-specific. If you want to know what it does on your printer, the only way to find out for sure is to test it yourself.